# The Day After Yom Kippur, Does The Community Re-Excommunnicate People Who Were Excommunicated Before Kol Nidre?

Tags: yom-kippur, nedarim-shevuot, cherem, kol-nidre, nidui-ostracism

Since we permit to pray with those who were excommunicated (I mean menudim or muhramim i.e. in niduy or 'herem) in Kol Nidre, does the community need to reinstitute relevant niduyim/haramot the day after Yom Kippur? E.g. Someone refusing to grant a get for a while who had niduy imposed. 11th of Tishrey comes, he still refuses. What now?

Comment: Can you cite "we permit to pray with those who were excommunicated"? After all, it serves as the premise for your whole question.

Comment: @msh210 I think he refers to the introduction to the Kol Nidrei prayer https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Yom_Kippur_Ashkenaz_Linear,_Kol_Nidrei.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I don't think that part of the prayer removes the excommunication, it just 'allows' those who are excommunicated to join in the prayer in spite of their status.

Comment: @mbloch, could be. I guess we'll find out when the asker edits the citation into the question.

Answer (score 1):

On Yom Kippur we do not permit an excommunicated person to pray in the Shul. We permit an Avaryon (עבריין) to pray in the Shul. A excommunicated person is someone who is in Cherem (חרם). There is no mention of allowing an excommunicated person to join in the Shul on Yom Kippur.

Here is a [link](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33693&st=&pgnum=410) to see the entire Kol Nidrei where there is no mention of excommunicated people.

Comment: Consider citing the relevant text on which you base yourself.